# Why are templates so slow to compile?

Tags: c++, templates, code-generation, compilation

Large templated projects are slow to compile, the STL being a main culprit of this it seems from empiric evidence. But, why is it slow to compile?

I've optimized builds before by watching for header includes and by combining compilation units, but I don't get why template libraries are quite so slow to compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Templated code has to be taken as another language to generate C++ code.

In this way of thinking, templated code has to be parsed, executed, then the compiler can generate C++ code that has to be added to the current unit file, and then we can compile the whole C++ code.

I've heard that not all compilers do this exactly but that's the main idea, and that suppose that there is a lot more happening before really compiling the code as some of the code has to be generated first.

Comment: It's slow because the writers of gcc and probabbly vc++ don't bother to reuse the template specializations and now since the standard is full of templates if you use a std::vector<your_structure> in 10 files this whole process is going on 10 times. Which is killing this language

Comment: @MartinKosicky Why would generating the code can cause such a slowness in compile time?

Comment: @piepi because even though O(10n) and O(n) are considered the same I call them 10 times slower.  That is what happens if you use std::basic_string<char,... in 30 different files

Answer (score 20):

C++ in general is slow to compile because of the ancient include mechanism, which causes the compiler to recursively re-parse every header with all its declarations and definitions and all that's included *for every translation unit*.

Templates just build on that "feature". But they require all *code* to be in headers, too, forcing the compiler to also re-parse all *implementations* of all templates included.

Comment: When you down-vote an answer for the first few times, a box pops up asking you to explain why you did so. After a while this doesn't happen anymore. However, that isn't because you shouldn't explain down-votes anymore, but because you are required to know that by then. To say it boldly: __You should still explain why you down-vote.__

Comment: Not sure, but maybe a C fanboy came through and thought "the ancient include mechanism is fine, C compiles fast enough with it"

Comment: Precompiled headers help solve that problem - you can have the entire STL precompiled so it's only parsed once when compiling a project.

Comment: @AshleysBrain: But then you end up having all of the standard library (of which the STL, BTW, is just one part) included everywhere. The viral include proliferation of PCH's made me hate them. If you're using GCC, DistGCC (or however it's spelled) is a better solution; on Windows it's [http://www.xoreax.com](IncrediBuild).

Comment: I really agree with this down vote stupidity... anyway, I think modules are still considered for the next standard (after C++0x). Also note that precompiled headers does not mean including everything, looking at Clang (and the possibility of serializing ASTs) it should be possible to avoid the parsing phase (the slowest of all), I'd really be interested in that.

Comment: This answer is only a partial answer. It does not address template slowness that happens when a template is not included multiple times or is defined only in a cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is in your question. You can't watch for header includes with templates, because the full implementation must be included into every compilation unit that uses them.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what a real-world template is -- it's not an actual thing, but directions on how to build actual things.

In the case of C++ templates, the header file doesn't contain an actual, e.g. 'vector', but instructions on how to build a `vector`.  Every time we build a source file that `#include`s `<vector>`, the compiler has to build new `vector` code, perhaps multiple times if we are instantiating `vector`s with different template parameters.

The build of each source file is independent, and doesn't know if you've already built a `vector` for another source file, so it builds a new one each time.